# Choosing the right opamp for a charge sensitive pre-amplifier circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am preparing to build a charge sensitive pre-amp for use with a gas filled proportional counter. Here is an (idealized) schematic for a CSP:
[image: csp]

But in all my reading they are referencing idealized opamps. Broadly speaking, what opamps make good CSPs? I currently have a few different opamps in my supplies:

- ADA4530 (advertised as electrometer grade)
- OPA128
- LM11

What parameters should be considered when choosing the opamp? Input bias current seems to be a big deal with electrometer grade opamps. Or is the choice of opamp not so important compared to choosing the right values of Cf and Rf?

Comment: A really important factor to consider when choosing an op amp is what voltages do you have available to power the op amp, and related is what voltages do you expect tour input and output to be. Some op amps are rail to rail, while others expect inputs or outputs to be several volts away from rail voltages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find enough information about "gas filled proportional counter". However, it sounds like as sensitive device as other ionization detectors. I use [ADA4530](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4530-1.pdf) for one of my Electrometers as well. I can measure sub pA level using this OPA. 
Since you are going to detect small amount of charge (ion), the front-end needs to be very low bias/leakage current OPA. Meantime, due to the high gain, input offset voltage  has to be low. And, the drift of those parameters should be low, too.
Meantime, since you are just starting, follow the design guidelines in the datasheet. Besides all the design aspects for low noise high resolution (I use 24bit ADC), don't forget shielding (cage), no conformal coating, and absolutely clean assembly. In case, try ceramic coating on FR4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use op_amp with High Input Impedance,low bias current, low noise, low bias current and wide bandwidth like OPA656.

Please see the below paper for more dtails.Hope this will help you.

https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/charge_amp_kacc9001e.pdf

Answer (score 2):

From your description it seems something like a charge amplifier like the ones used for piezoelectric accelerometers. I'd look at input impedance, input current bias and current noise, in that order.